# Eclipse field moving doesn't update the references

Tags: eclipse

I do Refactor->Move for a public field to move it to another class, but eclipse doesn't update its references. Is it not supported?
Version 4.2.1, included in ADT.

Comment: For what language? With what version? Obtained from where?

Comment: Do have a flawless code? Any compiletime errors or warnings? Do you get any error- or warning messages?